# C++ class member variable initialize once

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to make sure a c++ class member variable can be initialized only from inside the constructor. It should not be set or overwritten by memory overflow. What can you suggest me for that?

Comment: make the variable const. and overflow are undefined behavior so you can't control that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the member `const`, it can be initialized in a constructor member initializer but it cannot be assigned. That may not protect it from memory overruns, however. I'm not sure anything would.